# How to get balance by any address using rpc bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

How to get balance of any address using rpc bitcoind?

I mean getting by address the list of his unspent outputs in view something like this: TxHash;Value;Noutput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possible way to get balance by any address using rpc bitcoind.

You can only get balance of your's wallet adresses.

Answer (score 4):

You would run the `listunspent` response through a loop and total up all the values from all the unspent outputs for that address.

Comment: `listunspent` working only with addresses in your walett

Comment: @Denis Yes, Bitcoin Core does not track the balance of every address. Only of the combined balance of your entire wallet.