# Can I, and how do I query the Bitcoin Core wallet to give me a list of all transactions for any specified address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, python

I've read some conflicting things on this.  Given any address, what would be the json command and or how would I import into python, such a query to my bitcoin core wallet for an array of all the tx id's for all tx's associated with any given address (whether part of my wallet or not)?

Or is there even a way to do that to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

You question deserves a very long explanation :-) Instead of repeating what was already discussed, I put some links here which will help you to begin.

> Given any address, what would be the json command and or how would I
>   import into python...

first it is important to understand, that the wallet that you talk to (via RPC) is not the blockchain. You can only fetch information for the [known addresses](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58242/how-to-get-balance-by-any-address-using-rpc-bitcoind) in the wallet.

> ... for an array of all the tx id's for all tx's associated with any
>   given address (whether part of my wallet or not)?

This is a repeating pattern here in the forum, a quick [search revealed this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21375/how-to-retrieve-all-transactions-from-bitcoind?rq=1).

And how to send python commands to RPC is [described here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36433/bitcoin-rpc-works-in-bitcoin-cli-but-not-in-python-bitcoinrpc-no-json-object). A quick search for "RPC python" reveals many more sources of information. 
The RPC commands themselves are well [described here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)) [and here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list).

For sure we can't write the code for you, so maybe show us a bit how far you got, and then we can easily follow where you got stuck, and maybe even provide the help you are looking for.